# Error in compiling TikZ picture with standalone package

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files, standalone

I am trying to use the `standalone` package to externalize my Ti*k*Z graphics. In my setup I have a main `.tex` file, call it `main.tex` and the Ti*k*Z code is in another `.tex` file, call it `graphic.tex` in the same directory. On its own, `graphics.tex`, compiles fine and outputs a `.pdf` file with the intended image. However, if I try to call `graphics.tex` from within `main.tex` using the `\includestandalone` command I get an image that has some elements out of place. Here is a MWE for `main.tex` that produces the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{tipa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{tipa}{m}{n}{<->tipa10}{}
\newcommand{\arc@char}{{\usefont{U}{tipa}{m}{n}\symbol{62}}}%

\newcommand{\arc}[1]{\mathpalette\arc@arc{#1}}

\newcommand{\arc@arc}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \vbox{
    \hbox{\resizebox{\wd0}{\height}{\arc@char}}
    \nointerlineskip
    \box0
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\includestandalone{graphic}
\end{document}
```

and here is the code for `graphic.tex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{tipa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{tipa}{m}{n}{<->tipa10}{}
\newcommand{\arc@char}{{\usefont{U}{tipa}{m}{n}\symbol{62}}}%

\newcommand{\arc}[1]{\mathpalette\arc@arc{#1}}

\newcommand{\arc@arc}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \vbox{
    \hbox{\resizebox{\wd0}{\height}{\arc@char}}
    \nointerlineskip
    \box0
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[use as bounding box] (-4.9,-4.1) rectangle (4.9,5.1);
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(160:4){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(127:4){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(20:4){D}
  \tkzDefPoint(55:4){C}
  \tkzDefPoint(3.75,-2){X} % For Legend
  \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDrawSegments(A,D B,C)
  \tkzDrawPoint[size=10](O)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above left](A,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above right](C,D)
  \tkzDrawArc[R with nodes, color=blue, very thick,>=Stealth,arrows=<->](O,5)(D,A) %Create arc centered at origin with a radius of 4.75 that starts at D and ends at A
  \tkzDrawArc[R with nodes, color=red, very thick,>=Stealth,arrows=<->](O,4.5)(B,A)
  \tkzDrawArc[R with nodes, color=green!60!black, very thick,>=Stealth,arrows=<->](O,4.75)(C,B)
  \shade[ball color=blue] (X) circle (0.1cm) node[right=0.1cm]{$\arc{AD}$};
  \shade[ball color=green!60!black] ($ (X)+(0,-0.5) $) circle (0.1cm) node[right=0.1cm]{$\arc{BC}$};
  \shade[ball color=red] ($ (X)+(0,-1) $) circle (0.1cm) node[right=0.1cm]{$\arc{AB}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can have it compile correctly? I am aware I can include just use `\includegraphics` to insert the `.pdf` file of the graphic but the disadvantage is that any formatting changes (text, text size) are not going to be reflected in the graphic.

Comment: Which elements are out of place? [This is the standalone](http://i.imgur.com/x2AceAM.png) I get and [this is how it gets included in the main.tex](http://i.imgur.com/t0HExQG.png). By the way, you should replace `problem42_1` with `graphic` in the first MWE above.

Comment: On my computer the arcs above the arc names in the legend appear in the circle.

Comment: Do you want me lend you my laptop? I'm just going out shopping:) Make sure your tex distribution is updated. Which tex distro by the way, which engine and on what OS?

Comment: Good one! I'm using Tex Live on Antergos (Arch Linux derivative) and compiling with xelatex..

Comment: Yep, compiling with xelatex throws the arcs in the circle. But using another def for the `\arc`, for example `\newcommand{\arc}{\wideparen}` (`\wideparen` from the `yhmath` package) looks fine. So there's something fishy with the arc def you use or something.

Comment: @cfr It is not tipa, you get the same problem if you use a simple X as arc@char. The problem is the resizebox, one get a problem already with a simple graphic like `\tikz\node{\resizebox{1cm}{10\height}{yyyyyyyyy}};`. Probably at the end it is a problem of nested resizeboxes (`\includestandalone` calls it too).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good to know. I know `tipa` is not considered very satisfactory now and that is a reason to move to XeTeX/LuaTeX, if you need its facilities. And I know there were problems with this combination, but I should have checked the details.

Comment: Since the compilation doesn't come out correctly using xelatex. Is it possible to make  xelatex call latex to compile the images or ones experiencing the same problem